# Strange behavior of jquery.hotkeys

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although the subject of keyboard shortcuts has been treated here often, I cannot account for the following.

1) I put up a jQuery dialog

```
function statements ()
{  

 /* Initialization */
  $.ajax
   ({
      url: '/comeAndGo/MOVEMENTS/statements.php',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'html',
      async: false,
      success: function (data) { $('#mainContainer').html(data); },
      error: function () { alert("Error"); }
   });

   $("#DLG_Statements").dialog(
   {
         title:"Statements",
        height: 560, width: 600,
        modal: true,
        position: {my: "top", at: "top+60"},
        buttons:
        [
            {
                id: "bCancel",
                text: "Dismiss",
                click: function ()
                {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    location.href = gPath + "homePage.php";
                }
            },
            {
                id: "bOK",
                text: "OK",
                click: function () {}
            }
        ],
        draggable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false, // (5)
        resizable: false
   });

   $(document).bind('keydown', 'Alt+j', function () { alert ('jquery.hotkeys'); });        
}
```

2) The *DLG_Statements* is within a `<div>` inside a form which is part of *statements.php*. It includes several input elements such as radio buttons, drop-down menus, text input, a check-box.

MY PROBLEM

1) The jquery.hotkeys call does not respond when the cursor is positioned inside certain div's such as a text input field;
2) The jquery.hotkeys call responds unpredictably (it does/it does not) as a consequence of my clicking in different zones of the dialog;
3) The jquery.hotkeys call does not respond at all if I try and be more specific as to the jQuery wrapper, e.g. `$("#DLG_Statements").bind (etc.)`

What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you see any `failure` option for jQuery ajax method??? And please, don't use any sync request, it is deprecated and anyway there is no use case for it

Comment: Your remarks might be true but shed no light on the issue. That is why I am not going to raise objections: frustation is by no means what I aimed to when I asked for help.

Comment: Are you able to replicate issue on jsfiddle? It would make easier to provide any help

Comment: Know what jsfiddle is but never done it. I will give it a go and keep you updated.

Comment: On second thoughts I have decided to relinquish the use of  jquery.hotkeys: with a few lines of classical coding, I can solve my problem without investigating far over the horizon —I find it often more convenient to write my own functions than trying to understand or adapt someone else's.